# Is it posible to hide a column field depending on selection on phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

So, is it possible that depending on the answer you do, a field comes up
For example this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pvA7.png)

As you can see, what I really want is:
If "no" is selected, then the blueprint_stock is not visible
If "yes" is selected, then the blueprint_stock is visible

Can this be possible somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: You will get better answers if you post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking to customize the phpMyAdmin interface, which isn't really possible in the way you're trying to do. It sounds like you'd be better off with some custom application code to implement your insert statements and provide a better graphical interface. The phpMyAdmin application isn't really meant for users to interact with your database.